# TypeORM query builder conditional where clause

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I am trying to attach a conditional where clause to the query.

I need some link to documentation or any hint how can I acheive that.

**Query:**

```
const usersQuery = await connection
.getRepository(User)
.createQueryBuilder("user")
.getMany();
```

Now here I want to add if I get a userId paramater, I want to inject where clause into the query instance.

e.g:

```
if(params.userId){
   usersQuery.where("user.id = :id", { id: params.userId });
}

if(params.email){
   usersQuery.where("user.email= :email", { email: params.email});
}
```

This is something I want to achieve but some how I am unable to find this in the docs. Can anyone provide me the docs or reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this way?

```
const usersQuery = await connection
  .getRepository(User)
  .createQueryBuilder("user")

if(params.userId){
   usersQuery.andWhere("user.id = :id", { id: params.userId });
}

if(params.email){
   usersQuery.andWhere("user.email= :email", { email: params.email});
}

const users = await usersQuery.getRawMany();
```

Answer (score 0):

check a npm package called [typeorm-difo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-difo). The plugin's goal is to facilitate writing "relations", "where" and "order" arguments for any  find method of an entity repository. With this plugin, it is not necessary to manually write the "relation" argument, it is inferred from the "where" argument. It is also possible to reduce nested objects by concatenating them with "." (period).

```
 userRepository.find({
     where: getWhere([
         {
             field: "firstName",
             searchTerm:"John",
         },
         {
             field: "company.name",
             searchTerm:"company",
         }
     ])
 });
```